# adapt python script to replace/escape particular characters of the input data

Tags: python, csv

I have the following python script:

```
import csv
with open("adzuna_0.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("adzuna_X.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(file_in)
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in):

        if len(row) == num_headers:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

it's used to validate a csv file I have by eliminating malformed data indexes--> ones with too many column values.

The thing is- I need to also replace `&` with `&amp;`, I tried to accomplish this by using the following snippet:

```
for line in file_in:
    line.replace('&','&amp;')
```

inserted right above the line `csv_in = csv.reader(file_in)`, but it didn't work, and I can't figure out why.

I also tried like this:

```
if len(row) == num_headers:
        html.escape(row)
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

also fail.

I've been trying a few different ways but I haven't been able to pin it down.

What's the most effective way to replace these undesirable characters in my code?

Comment: You need to do the replacement on the line, like you said. But you're trying to do it on the file descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the replacement on the line, like you said. But you're trying to do it on the file descriptor.

You'll need to do the escaping on each line of the file, before giving it to csv.reader:

```
import csv

def url_escaper(data):
    for line in data:
        yield line.replace('&','&amp;')


with open("adzuna_0.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("adzuna_X.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(url_escaper(file_in))
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in):

        if len(row) == num_headers:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

You can't do it directly over the results of enumerating over `csv.reader(...)` because that returns the parsed list of comma separated values. The escaper does the replacement as each line is read into `csv.reader`

Comment: Oh..a generator...Nice!

Comment: ah- I tried it but it said `global name 'datA' is not defined`

Comment: ah- ok- anyway- bravo. nice work- thank you for showing me this trick!